# How to prove the triangle inequality in the case of an n-sided polygon?

Tags: geometry, triangle-inequality

Basically, I want proof for
the statement that any particular side of an n-sided polygon is less than the sum of the lengths of its other sides. I tried proving it and I can successfully prove it for some given number of sides like 6 or 7 but I don't how I can generalize it and prove it for any n-sided polygon. Also is there a name for this or is it just an extended version of the triangular inequality?

Comment: Metric spaces...

Comment: Prove that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!